# Helper method called upon in model file, not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

In a create method in a controller I have:

```
if logged_in_admin?
  @invitation.set_ids
```

In the Invitation model:

```
def set_ids
  self.person_one_id = current_user.id
end
```

`current_user` is a method in app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb and defines the currently logged in user. I use this method successfully in many controller methods. However, for the use case above I get the error message `undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #<Invitation:0x007f699086bf40>`.

Why do I get this error message? Is this because this time I'm using the helper method in a model file and is this not allowed? If such is not allowed, what would be the best way to securely set `person_one_id` for `@invitation` equal to the id of the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current_user` not available in a model layer(it's `MVC`, your helpers on the `CV` layer and model know nothing about the `current_user` helper). Pass `user_id` from your helper as argument:

`some_helper.rb`

```
def my_helper
  if logged_in_admin?
    @invitation.set_ids(current_user.id)
# .....
```

`model.rb`:

```
def set_ids(user_id)
  self.person_one_id = user_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following line to your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    include SessionsHelper
end
```

Now you should be able to use the methods inside your controllers / models.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. I already have this in my application controller and helper methods are working in controllers. Just not in the model. I also wonder whether it is secure for this one occasion I need it, to immediately give all models access to all helper methods.

Comment: Including a helper class in the controller does **not** give models access to the helpers in this class.